# how to write/change the query string without causing the browser to load a new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

The first technique that I can write the Query string is using the submit's form.

I want to change the url without the redirect.

Old Url is

localhost:8080

and automatically adding foo=1&foo=2 (variable s) in the Url

localhost:8080?=foo=1&foo=2

There are other technique or means for writing?

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to ask.  Are you asking how to change the query string without causing the browser to load a new page?

Comment: When you make a request to `localhost:8080` there is no way to request `localhost:8080?=foo=1&foo=2` without redirecting the browser unless you use some htaccess url rewriting

Comment: @jfriend00 excatly and I update the question

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV How to  use some htaccess url rewriting

Comment: afaik, it is not possible. only way i know is to use `location.hash` and replace whole content using ajax. then if user clicks refresh page with hash in the url, you have to intercept it as early as possbile and do same aforementioned injection.

Answer (score 4):

You can manipulate the location url with the [HTML5 history API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html). Unfortunately, this only works on proper browsers.

Alternately you could use hash (#) instead of question mark in the URL. In your case `localhost:8080#foo=1&bar=1` using `location.href = '#foo=1&bar=1';` for example.

Don't know if this is possible in your case though.